# Selecting only coinciding points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, intersection, overlapping-features, select, extract

I have a lot of points in the same layer. Many of these are coinciding.  I only want the points that coincide slected or the points that don't coincide (then I can just reverse the selection). This is because I want to identify clusters that are more than 1 at the same place. Working with ArcMap (Standard license).

And is there a way of specifying selection of ex 10> coinciding points? Like I want to only select points that are coinciding and are 10 or more?

Comment: I believe Find Identical is not available for Standard License. I would suggest using Spatial Join using your point layer as BOTH target Features and and Join features and a one-to-many operation. This will create a new layer which will include only the coinciding features (more or less, the same output as Find Identical). Then, use summary statistics and join back as @BERA suggests

Comment: Yea. It is not included in the Standard. I will try this out. Thanks!